# When to apply Buoyant force to a Box2d body to simulate water?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I have been following a formula to calculate the buoyant force.

> Fb = ρgV

1. Fb - is the buoyant force
2. ρ - density of the liquid
3. g - gravity
4. V - volume of the object

My box2d body will always be submerged to the sensor so I don't have to detect what portion of the body is in the water, basically the entire body is always in the water and I will always apply the force to the center of the body.

```
body.applyForceTocenter(0, Fb, true);
```

If I apply the force on upon collision to the censor then it will just fall cause the force will only be applied once, and if I type this to the render method then the body will have too much force cause it is applied every frame. So how do I implement the force? and how to compute for the drag? so that it won't bounce.
If my understanding of buoyancy and how to implement it is wrong then please correct me.

Comment: There are some nice answers in the libGDX forum -http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=417

Comment: Have you checked out iforce2d's Buoyancy tutorial at http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/buoyancy ? I love his tutorials and believe his buoyancy one can help answer your questions.